# Windows batch scripting - where to put a .bat such that it can be called from anwhere?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I know how to do this with a bash script on *n*x - by placing it in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.

Where in the Windows (7) file system should I place a **.bat** such that it can be called from any directory I'm in on the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some directory that is mentioned in your `PATH` environment variable. Actually that's exactly the same as in Unix-like systems.

Mind you, it's probably easiest to just create a directory for that and add it to `PATH` than throwing them in random locations where they don't belong (such as `system32`).

Comment: You'll find out which directories are inside the path using 

`echo %PATH%`

Comment: ... or with `set PATH` or just `path`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either put it in a location in the `PATH` variable or create a new one in there.

You can do this in Windows (Vista and above, probably similar in XP) by right clicking `Computer => Properties => Advanced System Settings => Advanced => Environment Variables`.

Find the `PATH` variable, and either add your batch file to a path in there or add a new path of your choice separated from the others with a semi colon `;`.